# Remove the full hash / anchor from a URL using `$location`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I remove the full hash / anchor from a URL using the `$location` object in angularJS?

For example, I have the following url http://www.myurl.com/town/street, I am using anchor links in my page and I wish to remove the hash/anchor when a user clicks a link that toggles the visibility of a div/content (using `ng-show`), my code below tries to remove an existing hash/anchor like http://www.myurl.com/town/street#houses however I have notice that when I seem to have the following url http://www.myurl.com/town/street##houses using the code below so my $anchorScroll() doesn't work, then it changes my url to http://www.myurl.com/town/street#/%23houses#houses

```
if($location.hash().length > 0){
   $location.path('#' + $location.hash()).replace();
}

   $location.hash(toggleTarget);
   $anchorScroll();
```

How do I just remove the full hash / anchor? Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to use anchor links to scroll to content but you don't want the url to change (adding the hash at the end) ?

Comment: No, I just want to remove the hash/anchor from the url programatically - perhaps my description above is misleading

Comment: So when a user hides a div the hash for that content should be removed from the URL?

Comment: Yes, absolutley! That's what I want to do

Comment: Have you tried push state... something like `history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname+window.location.search);))` to remove the hash ?